# List of abstract class

Tags: c#, list, abstract

I have abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract string nazwa
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

And two classes which inherit from MyClass:

```
public class MyClass1 : MyClass
{
    public override string nazwa
    {
        get { return "aaa"; }
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public override string nazwa
    {
        get { return "bbb"; }
    }
}
```

In another class I create List:

```
List<MyClass> myList;
```

Now I want to create

```
myList = new List<MyClass1>;
```

The compiler show an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Program.MyClass1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Program.MyClass>'
```

I must be some easy way to convert it... I cannot find anything useful

Comment: While an implicit conversion might not work, you can try an explicit conversion.  By casting for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What's the use of reusing the simple reference var `myList` ? Just create a new variable.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there a particular way that you want to use the class that could not be accomplished through instantiating it as new List<MyClass>()?

Comment: Because MyClass1 and MyClass2 in my program have different properties. And it depends from user choice, which one is being used. And in some funcions I want to use properties which are in both classes. it is complicated ;P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create the list as the base type:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Which you can then add derived items to:

```
myList.Add(new MyClass2());
```

Comment: You are right, that I don't need to create List<MyClass2>, to add there items of MyClass2. It works, thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Joel Beckham! It works like a charm! I have been looking for a solution to this everywhere, thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

It is not safe to convert a `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>`.

What do you expect to happen if you write

```
List<MyClass1> derivedList = ...
List<MyClass> baseList = derivedList;
baseList.Add(new MyClass2());    //Boom!
```

You're asking for *covariance*; covariance is only possible with read-only interfaces.
Thus, `IEnumerable<Derived>` is convertible to `IEnumerable<Base>`.

Answer (score 3):

You must have a base class list, and later you can use Linq to get the MyClas1 item list when you need it.

```
 List<MyClass> BaseList = new ...

 BaseList.FillWithItems();

 List<MyClass1> DerivedList = BaseList.OfType<MyClass1>().ToList();
```